# android: add line to each item in List View

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created the simple list view with base adapter.Now I want to add the simple line after the each item in list view.can anyone please tell how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a bit? Are you trying to add a line of text after each item, or a horizontal line? Are you using a layout file for your list items?

Comment: yes i m using the layout file for that but now get the answer,http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider and set the android:deviderHeight also to 2 dip thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
  This done using the [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3adivider)

Please not forget to set the android:deviderHeight otherwise it will not show.

Thank for support